# Collation conflict using 2 versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I am working on 2 versions of SQL Server i.e 2005 and 2008 R2.

From 2008 R2 I have created a linked server which will connect to an older SQL Server 2005 instance.

I have one table on my server (2008) which is as below

members

```
id                  name     
0002320         AOne Enterprises Motihari
0002321         AOne Enterprises Siliguri
```

Another table which resides on remote server contain activity of each agent

```
id  member_code agent   rr_no   txn_date    amount
```

I fired a query below

```
select top 5 * 
from [192.168.6.3].sync.dbo.agents_log
where member_code IN 
      (select id from members where name like 'AOne Enterprises%')
```

I was trying to pull all activity log of AOne Enterprises through out the country which is in distributed database , so I need to create a link servers.

I got this error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

not exactly sure what you need, but if its only collation issue you can do below

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM   [192.168.6.3].sync.dbo.agents_log
WHERE  member_code COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
IN (SELECT id
    FROM   members
    WHERE  NAME LIKE 'AOne Enterprises%')
```

I just added **COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** , perhaps it work